# Database Query: Importing data from an excel spreadsheet. Without it opening that spreadsheet.

Tags: database, excel

I am doing a database query import from another excel spreadsheet.  And every time it updates it opens up the spreadsheet that it is pulling the information from.  I do not want this to happen. Any thoughts on what I should look into to stop this from happening?

Comment: I think you need more info here, what database backend and what specific method are you using to import the data (Preferably with a code sample).

Comment: "Import External Data" "New Database Query" "Excel Document" is the type of database. My code does not call the query.  It is on a timer in the query properties.  It messes up my code because it opens up a copy of the other excel spreadsheet.  My code errors out when it references a sheet because it thinks the copy of the other spreadsheet is the active workbook.  I need a way to say "On Error" make "Assembly" active workbook.

Comment: Querying an open workbook causes memory leaks. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319998   The article is for ADO but I believe this applies to Excel's built in query engine as well. I learned this the hard way.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think that this workbook being open could lead to other problems, to get a handle back to your workbook try...

```
If Err.Number = (The error number you get) then
    Set xlWorkbook = GetObject("C:\Test\MyWb.xlsx", "Excel.Application")
end if
```